# WordPress global $post variable is empty

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress plugin(managing background image), when I try to use

```
global $post;
print_r($post);
```

the object is empty. 
Probably there is some required data (I dont know what.)
Please help me if you know.

Comment: Try to be more specific about what you're trying to do. Also, where do you put the code above - in a function, plugin file ?

Comment: The `$post` global variable only *works* within the **WP Loop**, are you using it inside the loop?

Comment: @MikO !! thanks for your time. I got the error. I was not using it inside the loop. my mistake.
Thanks again.

Comment: @muaaz, No problem, I'm happy this helped! I added this as an answer to make it more visible to other users with the same problem...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The WordPress global variable [**$post**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/%24post) contains the data of the current *Post* within the [***The Loop***](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

This means that WordPress will assign a value to this variable in each loop iteration. Consecuently, if you're trying to access `$post` from anywhere in your code outside the WP loop, it will be of course empty...

Comment: This is correct. To add, if you want to get the post data/ID for the current post you are on (instead of the current post in the loop), you can use get_queried_object(). https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/